# 128 Bit AES Issue

Tags: aes, implementation

I'm trying to use the 128bit TI_aes implementation on my 16bit microcontroller and I'm having the weirdest issue.

Every input where <strike>two bytes within a word are identical</strike>  *two nibbles within a byte are identical* is successfully encrypting and decrypting but every other input is not working.

For example:
input:

00112233445566778899aabbccddeeff - Successfully encrypting & decrypting.
182787cebc51b64f1e854deea460bcea - not working.

The only modification I did to the original code is to AND every shift operation with 0xff because the TI_aes implementation is for 8bit microcontroller so in case of a shift left my 16bit microcontroller will still have the MSB bit instead of discarding it.

Example:
When shifting 10100111 one left we'll get 01001110 but in 16bit microcontroller it'll be
0000000010100111 ---> 0000000101001110 AND 0xff --> 00000000001001110

Any ideas how comes it successfully encrypts/decrypts certain inputs while others not?

Comment: @fgrieu - You can find the code here: http://ideone.com/pAmlWM. Thx!

Comment: I'm inclined to believe the error is not in `aes_enc_dec`as posted, but in some other code calling it and making the conclusion stated in the question. Also, `00112233445566778899aabbccddeeff` (assuming that is an AES block) does not match the condition _"two bytes within a word are identical"_, but rather _two nibbles within a byte are identical_, so perhaps the problem is in the conversion from hex to bytes or/and back, perhaps in endianness or character parity in that conversion.

Comment: @fgrieu you are right. it's "two nibbles within a byte are identical". the AES block is a uint8 array with 16 members but the memory saves each byte in a word block.

Comment: If indeed _"the memory saves each byte in a word block"_ with _"word block"_ anything else than an octet, then you have a pointer type problem (which the compiler should bark about if properly set up, and you neither cast pointers nor use an unsafe `union`): the interface to `aes_enc_dec` is passed the block as an `unsigned char *`, which most often is the same as a pointer to `uint8_t` from `<stdint.h>`, which always is an octet; only you can know what `uint8` is, and can sort out the different types.

Comment: @fgrieu - Thanks a lot for all the inputs... I'll check it later on and update, much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem described in the question and its comments is not in [the code](http://ideone.com/pAmlWM), but probably in how it is called. At least, on a conformant compiler, it passes the short test program at the end of this answer. We are hinted by the comment *"the memory saves each byte in a word block"* that there is some problem with the data type used for the 16 octets holding the AES block.

---

Also, a hasty modification of the original code (alluded to in the question) has introduced a huge vulnerability to [timing attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timing_attack). We have gone from about the following

```
// multiply by 2 in the galois field
unsigned char galois_mul2(unsigned char value) {
    signed char temp;
    // cast to signed value
    temp = (signed char) value;
    // if MSB is 1, then this will signed extend and fill the temp variable with 1's
    temp = temp >> 7;
    // AND with the reduction variable
    temp = temp & 0x1b;
    // finally shift and reduce the value
    return ((value << 1)^temp);
}
```

which likely executes in time independent of `value` (but makes a non-portable assumption about what `temp >> 7` gives), to the following

```
unsigned char galois_mul2(unsigned char value) {
    if (value>>7) {
        value = (value << 1) & 0xff;
        return (value^0x1b);
    } else
        return value<<1;
}
```

which in all likelihood compiles to code with a horrible data timing dependency.

To fix this problem, the standard technique is

```
unsigned char galois_mul2(unsigned char value) {
    return ( ( 0u - ( value >> 7 ) ) & 0x1b ) ^ ( value << 1 );
}
```

which, under the sole assumption that `unsigned char` is an octet, works with any standards-abiding C compiler, and most others. The generated code should still be checked for lack of data-dependent timing variations. It should be possible to remove the `0u`, but some compilers in their default setting will object to taking the unary negative of an unsigned, even though that's well-defined. Some compilers for 8-bit CPUs will needlessly juggle with multi-octet intermediary results, and should be hinted that it is pointless using casts, like

```
return (unsigned char)((unsigned char)-(unsigned char)(value>>7)&0x1b)
     ^ (unsigned char)(value<<1);
```

---

Depending on target CPU, its settings, and the compiler, `aes_enc_dec` could have other data-dependent timing variations enabling timing attack, in particular due to cache effects.

Another security issue is that the whole thing is not intended to resist [Differential Power Analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_analysis#Differential_power_analysis), and yet other classic and potentially devastating attacks, like [fault attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_fault_analysis) (also see Hagai Bar-El, Hamid Choukri, David Naccache, Michael Tunstall and Claire Whelan [*The Sorcerer’s Apprentice Guide to Fault Attacks*](http://eprint.iacr.org/2004/100)).

---

A short test showing that the code does not exhibit the problem alleged in the question and comments:

```
int main(void) {
    // a known-good key/plaintext/ciphertext triplet; could be const if environement supports that
    unsigned char rk[] = {0x4e,0xb1,0x19,0x72,0x33,0x1a,0x6f,0xcf,0xdc,0x9e,0x57,0x32,0x92,0x39,0x97,0x31};
    unsigned char rp[] = {0x18,0x27,0x87,0xce,0xbc,0x51,0xb6,0x4f,0x1e,0x85,0x4d,0xee,0xa4,0x60,0xbc,0xea};
    unsigned char rc[] = {0xd8,0x7c,0x9c,0x86,0xd9,0x2c,0xdd,0x8c,0x48,0x54,0x82,0x47,0x19,0xf8,0xc6,0x21};

    unsigned char vb[16], vk[16], vj, vx = 0;   // block, key, index, errors
    for(vj=0;vj<16;++vj) {
        vb[vj] = rp[vj];        // prepare block
        vk[vj] = rk[vj];        // prepare key
    }
    aes_enc_dec(vb, vk, 0);     // encipher
    for(vj=0;vj<16;++vj) {
        vx |= vb[vj]^rc[vj];    // check encryption
        vk[vj] = rk[vj];        // prepare key
    }
    aes_enc_dec(vb, vk, 1);     // decipher
    for(vj=0;vj<16;++vj) {
        vx |= vb[vj]^rp[vj];    // check decryption
    }
    if (vx!=0)                  // if there was some error..
        while(1);               // hang
    return 0;                   // exit with sucess
}
```

Comment: you are right. I figured it out and it was a uint8 casting that didn't cast. I used a pseudo-random 16bit function to generate the AES block and I did casting to divide upper and lower 8bits to into uint8 variables. the problem was that is didn't actually perform the casting and the AES block wasn't what I expected it to be.

I didn't see it at first because when printing the variables it actually showed like it was okay... I noticed it only when I debugged it directly from memory.

Sorry for all the hassle and thank you for all the knowledge sharing!